# Finding all the points within a circle in 2D space

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, optimization, geometry

I am representing my 2D space (consider a window), where each pixel is shown as a cell in a 2D array. i.e. a 100x100 window is represented by the array of same dimensions.

Now given a point in the window, if I draw a circle of radius `r`, I want to find all the points lying in that circle.

I was thinking I'd check for the each point in the square region around the radius, with `side = 2*r`, if it lies in the circle or not. I'll use the normal distance formula maybe?

Hence, maybe the following:

```
for (x=center-radius ; x<center+radius ; x++){
    for (y=center-radius ; y<center+radius; y++) {
        if (inside) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Will it serve my purpose? Can I make it faster?

Comment: To simulate the pi number, a uniform distributed random values are generated with the xx+yy<=rr restriction. I think that could be a very good idea put random values in and then search the neighbors like the hill climbing algorithm.

Comment: Use Pythagoras Theorem to determine whether the distance of the current "cell" is within the circle or not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Will it serve my purpose?

For your 100x100, yes.

> Can I make it faster?

Yes. For example, you can:

- Check only 1 quadrant and get other points because of symmetry.
- Skip the square root when calculating the distance.

Code:

```
for (x = xCenter - radius ; x <= xCenter; x++)
{
    for (y = yCenter - radius ; y <= yCenter; y++)
    {
        // we don't have to take the square root, it's slow
        if ((x - xCenter)*(x - xCenter) + (y - yCenter)*(y - yCenter) <= r*r) 
        {
            xSym = xCenter - (x - xCenter);
            ySym = yCenter - (y - yCenter);
            // (x, y), (x, ySym), (xSym , y), (xSym, ySym) are in the circle
        }
    }
}
```

That's about 4x speed up.

[JS tests](http://jsperf.com/point-in-circle/2) for solutions presented here. Symmetry is the fastest on my computer. Trigonometry [presented by Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856411/finding-all-the-points-within-a-circle-in-2d-space#answer-15856534) is very clever, but it involves expensive mathematical functions like `sin` and `acos`, which have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: You say for 100X100 it works. Will it not work for some other dimension?

Comment: It will always work. The question is, how fast. In dimension d=2 it's O(r^2), where r is radius. In d=3 it's O(r^3), we are looking for points in a sphere. Generally it's O(r^d). Your question was "will it serve my purpose", which I understand as "will it run so quickly that I will not feel it". I said yes, because for r = 100 and d = 2 on modern computers, even in JS, time will not be noticeable. However, for bigger r or d the time will be noticeable.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I meant if the dimension 100X100 was something else, i.e. 500X300 or anything.

Comment: Yes, it will work. The speed is indifferent to the size of grid. What matters is the size of radius. Algorithm's complexity is O(r^d). Only r (radius) and d (dimension) matters.

Comment: As an ES6 array comprehension `[ /* (x, y) (-x, -y) are in circle */  for (x of r) for (y of r) if ((x - center)*(x - center) + (y - center)*(y - center) < rad*rad)];` 

Try it in FF

Comment: This didn't work for me and the performance went bad.

Comment: JS Test link returns `500`.

Answer (score 6):

You can bypass the need for a conditional check:

```
for(x=center-radius; x<center+radius; x++) {
    yspan = radius*sin(acos((center-x)/radius));
    for(y=center-yspan; y<center+yspan; y++) {
        // (x,y) is inside the circle
    }
}
```

If needed, you can `round(yspan)`.

Comment: I assume, if you have diff coords for x-center and y-center that it changes to
first for loop: center = xcenter, yspan: center = xcenter and second for loop center = ycenter?

Comment: Yup. You can even use a different `radius` in the `for` and the `sin` to get an ellipse.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala See my comment directly above yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can get speed ups by computing as much outside of the loops as possible. Also there's no need to do the Pythagoras Theorem square root... just keep everything squared. One final speed-up can be made by only doing the math for one quarter of the circle (because it's symmetrical)... when a match is found you just replicate it for the other three quarters.

```
radiusSquared = radius*radius;
rightEdge = centerX+radius;
bottomEdge = centerY+radius;
for(x = centerX; x <= rightEdge; x++){
    xSquared = x*x;
    for(y = centerY; y <= bottomEdge; y++){
        ySquared = y*y;
        distSquared = xSquared+ySquared;
        if(distSquared <= radiusSquared){
            // Get positions for the other quadrants.
            otherX = centerX-(x-centerX);
            otherY = centerY-(y-centerY);
            // Do something for all four quadrants.
            doSomething(x, y);
            doSomething(x, otherY);
            doSomething(otherX, y);
            doSomething(otherX, otherY);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting a list of all points within a circle you should use:

```
var radius = 100, r2 = radius * radius;
var circle = [];
for (var dx = -radius; dx <= radius; dx++) {
  var h = Math.sqrt(r2 - dx * dx) | 0;
  for (var dy = -h; dy <= h; dy++) {
    circle.push([dx, dy])
  }
}
```

See http://jsperf.com/circles/2 for profiling against the other solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

#### If the following is true:

```
( ( xPos - centreX)^2 + (yPos - centreY)^2 ) <= radius^2
```

where `xPos` and `yPos` are the coordinates of a point you're checking, then the point is inside your circle.

Comment: My solution's [more than an order of magnitude faster](http://jsperf.com/point-in-circle) ;)

Comment: My code was under the impression he had to do it in fewest possible characters *cough* :D

Answer (score 0):

seems correct. you can make it slightly faster by finding minY and then doing DoSomething from   -rangeY to +rangeY for the current X.

```
for(dx=0;dx<rad; dx++)
{
  rangeY = 0;
  while (!inside(x, rangeY)) //inside == check if x*x + y*y <r*r
    rangeY++;

  for(y=center-rangeY;y<center+rangeY;y++) 
  {
    DoSomething(centerX - dx, y);
    DoSomething(centerX + dx, y);      }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this question has an accepted answer, but I have a far easier solution. The other answers confused me, as I did not know what `center`, `xcenter`, `ycenter` were, and the math behind the functions were left unexplained and I trekked out to discover a mathematical solution of my own.

My equation is very simple:

`cx` is the x point in the center of the circle

`cy` is the y point in the center of the circle

`rad` is the radius of the circle

What my equation/function does is calculate the points by calculating each possible point given the radius and it adds and subtracts the offset of `cx` and `cy`.

```
//Creates an array filled with numbers
function range(begin, end) {
    for (var i = begin, arr = []; i < end; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr;
}

function calculateAllPointsInCircle(cx, cy, rad) {

   var rang = range(-rad, rad + 1);
   var px = [];
   var py = [];
   var xy = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < rang.length; i++) {
     var x = cx + rang[i];
     px.push(x);

     for (var l - rang.length - 1; l > 0; l--) {
        var y = cy + rang[l];
        if (!py.indexOf(y)===-1) { py.push(y); }

        xy.push(x+','+y);
     }
   }

   return {
     x: x,
     y: y,
     xy: xy
   }
}
```

The performance is much higher than the other answers: http://jsperf.com/point-in-circle/4
You can check my equation with math, using the equation that will validate if a given point is inside a circle `x*x + y*y <= r*r` OR `x^2 + y^2 <= r^2`

**Edit- Super compressed ES6 version:**

```
function range(begin, end) {
  for (let i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
    yield i;
  }
}

function calculateAllPointsInCircle(cx, cy, rad) {
    return {
        x: [cx + i for (i of range(-rad, rad + 1))],
        y: [cy + i for (i of range(-rad, rad + 1))]
    };
}
```

Comment: wasted my time to check that its fast but not working