# Python all points on circle given radius and center

Tags: python, geometry, center

I wrote this function:

```
def get_x_y_co(circles):
    xc = circles[0] #x-co of circle (center)
    yc = circles[1] #y-co of circle (center)
    r = circles[2] #radius of circle
    arr=[]
    for i in range(360):
        y = yc + r*math.cos(i)
        x = xc+ r*math.cos(i)
        x=int(x)
        y=int(y)
        #Create array with all the x-co and y-co of the circle
        arr.append([x,y])
    return arr
```

With 'circles' being an array with `[X-center, Y-center, Radius]`

I would like to extract all the points with **integer resolution** present in the circle.
Right now, I realised I am creating an array of points who are on the BORDER of the circle, but I don't have access to the points INSIDE the circle.

**I thought of just reducing the radius, and iterate this for all values of the radius, until the radius is 0**

But I feel there is a much more efficient way. Any help is welcome

Comment: Aren't there an infinite number of points inside the circle?

Comment: I guess you mean points with integer resolution?

Comment: Yes I do, but I have an exercise asking to calculate the average color of the circle just given the radius and the center coords. I was thinking of just extracting all the pixels in the circle, and then calculating the mean value of the BGR values

Comment: Yes, with integer resolution

Comment: Then your basic approach is wrong: iterating over degrees. Iterate over the y-axis instead - this will give you one (top and bottom) or two x values to iterate between.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856411/finding-all-the-points-within-a-circle-in-2d-space Not in Python but can be easily ported.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help!

Comment: I came across this post looking for a way to generate points in a hollow circle, so the answer below doesn't really apply to my situation. I ran the code you supplied but it just generates a diagonal line. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
def points_in_circle(radius):
    for x, y in product(range(int(radius) + 1), repeat=2):
        if x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2:
            yield from set(((x, y), (x, -y), (-x, y), (-x, -y),))
list(points_in_circle(2))
```

> ```
> [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (0, -2), (0, 2), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, -1), (2, 0), (-2, 0)]
> ```

## with numpy

```
import numpy as np
def points_in_circle_np(radius):
    a = np.arange(radius + 1)
    for x, y in zip(*np.where(a[:,np.newaxis]**2 + a**2 <= radius**2)):
        yield from set(((x, y), (x, -y), (-x, y), (-x, -y),))
```

## with arbitrary center

```
def points_in_circle_np(radius, x0=0, y0=0, ):
    x_ = np.arange(x0 - radius - 1, x0 + radius + 1, dtype=int)
    y_ = np.arange(y0 - radius - 1, y0 + radius + 1, dtype=int)
    x, y = np.where((x_[:,np.newaxis] - x0)**2 + (y_ - y0)**2 <= radius**2)
    # x, y = np.where((np.hypot((x_-x0)[:,np.newaxis], y_-y0)<= radius)) # alternative implementation
    for x, y in zip(x_[x], y_[y]):
        yield x, y
```